# Move directory content once it was last modified (The directory) more than X time ago

Tags: linux, bash, fileserver

My question is as follows:
I am trying to create a "buffer" folder (Lets call it "PROCESS") for which i run a 'scp' command on any files in it (*), and mv them after to a dump folder ("BACKUP").
Now, i had a case in which the connection broke in the middle of my bash script thus leaving the files in the PROCESS folder.
In my script i have a check that if i have files in PROCESS folder, i will skip the script iteration (cron job running evey 1m), thus the script will always be skipped.

I need a command/code which checks if i have files in PROCESS folder that moved into the folder more than X time ago (120 mins for the example), and move them back to the "NEW" folder, is there an easy way to do so?

```
find /path/PROCESS -mmin +120 -exec mv /path/PROCESS/* /path/NEW
```

This is what i came to for now, but it doesn't appear to work unfortunately.
Please help :)

Comment: You have to use find's `{}` notation: `find /path/PROCESS -type f -mmin +120 -exec mv -t /path/NEW {} +`

Comment: Thanks for the response, this  command checks when the files were last modified -> moves them.  Is there a way to do this check on directory level?

Comment: To verify directories instead of files, change the `-type f` value to `-type d`.

Comment: Ok, -type d worked, but it moves the  whole NEW directory to PROCESS folder after it copies the files to NEW, any reason why?